# How to set up PHP 7 with NGINX

Tags: php, nginx, fastcgi

I installed PHP 7 Nightly and Nginx 1.9.7 (Mainline) on my development Debian Stable:

```
$ curl http://nginx.org/keys/nginx_signing.key | apt-key add -
$ echo -e 'deb http://nginx.org/packages/mainline/debian/ jessie nginx\ndeb-src http://nginx.org/packages/mainline/debian/ jessie nginx' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nginx.list
$ echo -e 'deb http://repos.zend.com/zend-server/early-access/php7/repos ubuntu/' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list
$ apt-get -y update && time apt-get -y dist-upgrade
$ apt-get -y --force-yes install --fix-missing nginx php7-nightly
$ service nginx restart
```

I have this configuration file in `/etc/nginx/conf.d/php.conf` (default.conf uncommented). It's the original default.conf, I just uncommented the PHP fastCGI lines:

```
    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        #charset koi8-r;
        #access_log  /var/log/nginx/log/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }

        # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
        #}

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        location ~ \.php$ {
            root           html;
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #    deny  all;
        #}
    }
```

I didn't found any tutorial on the net how to set up Nginx Mainline with PHP 7 yet. :(

Thank You!

Comment: If you use the PHP-FPM SAPI (FastCGI Process Manager), nginx is configured exactly the same as before. Using the FPM SAPI is typically a good option because it allows you to control the php processes independently from your webserver (versus having nginx manage the fastcgi processes), and the php environment doesn't have to be re-loaded from scratch on each request (versus using regular CGI).

Comment: Do you know any tutorial how to install php-fpm to php7? Is there a way to install it with package manager?

Comment: Looks like from php 5.3.3 it's included in the the core php package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After taking a quick look at the packages offered by zend (the packages you are installing), you'll have to write a script for your init system (systemd) to start and manage the php-fpm process.

The binaries are installed in `/usr/local/php7/sbin/php-fpm`. You'll also have to modify the configuration files in `/usr/local/php7/etc`. The main change will be to ensure that fpm has a pool listening on address *127.0.0.1* at port *9000*.

Comment: Thank You! I following this tutorial, right now I'm setting up a new Dockerfile so I'm a middle in the process, but looks this is the way to go: https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/install-php-7-on-debian-8-jessie/

Comment: I successfully setted up PHP7 with Nginx. Here is my Dockerfile for the working server: https://github.com/DJviolin/debian/blob/master/Dockerfile